# Unity hovering buildings before you place them for game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In strategy games it's common to have after you click the button to build a building, you are able to "hold" the building on the cursor, so you can place it where you want it to go. To do this, I need to have it initialize, then have it follow the users cursor with raycast.

What I need it to do:

1. Need to have the building initialize.
2. Need to have the building follow the cursor using raycast
3. On click, the building needs to place in a permanent spot, then destroy the old building.
4. The permanent building gets stored into an empty GameObject using the `Transform.SetParent` line. Creating a public variable for this above will allow it to be set in the game manager, rather than hard coded into a script.

Comment: Hello ! What did you try so far to do what you want ? Do you have a script like `class BuildingPlacement : MonoBehaviour` with methods in it or anything else ?

Comment: I haven't actually started on it yet. There are really three main parts to it. First, a script to have an outline of the building selected follow the cursor, which I don't know how to do. Then in that script a part that waits for a click to initialize the object- which I do know how to do. Part of that also involves getting it to place at the right spot, I am not sure how to get it to get the exact dimensions for initialization. So sorry I don't have much to work with, just looking for some suggestions before I get started.

Comment: I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656803/make-an-object-collide-with-certain-other-objects-when-moved-to-raycasthit-point/61661382#61661382) a question that may help you. It's not exactly what you ask here, but it could help to start there. Tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you will need to create code to update the position of the building to match the position of the cursor. You can get that by getting the `RaycastHit` point. You can do that by updating the translation of the building on every update to the current hit point.

You will likely need to keep track of the user being in some sort of building placement mode. A simple way to do that is by using a state machine.

Then, when the user clicks (or fires, or whatever you decide the appropriate mechanism is) you use that position to store the permanent position.

It's hard to give more details without know how you are tracking and storing the buildings. I'd assume it's something like an array, in which case, the second step simply involves adding the building to the array.

Comment: I'll try to figure that out. I am not too familiar with Unity and it's hard making a game that you don't enjoy making (I am doing it for a class and they gave us a list of ideas to make from. It's disappointing.) And the teacher is really bad.

Comment: Raycast is definitely what I need for having it place in the right spot (the ground and not the sky). And yeah it's building into an array. This definitely helps, thanks! All that I need now is to understand how to have an outline follow the mouse.Edit: Well I guess it's not typical to have it follow the mouse directly, it will probably follow the raycast of the mouse to the ground, as they are the same thing. I guess initialize a new temporary buildling, one with lower opacity or something, have it follow, then on click delete that and place the permanent? How to follow though? Suggestions?

Comment: I get that. I'm very experienced in C# but not so much in Unity, so I still remember getting started. I'd suggest starting with some of the excellent tutorials they offer to learn the UI and workflow, then you will more likely be able to understand more of my answer.

Comment: Yeah I've been working with some tutorials. Sometimes they can be hard to follow though. Plus I find there isn't many working with strategy games in particular. Oh well. Just a few questions on stackoverflow. I always seem to learn something new when I ask a question :)

Comment: If you don't already know about finite state machines, learn about them (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). I didn't for years, and ended up writing my own inferior versions for a long, long time before taking the time to properly understand them.